# MySQL performance problems after hardware upgrade and move to VM

Tags: centos, mysql, performance

Recently we've ran some (security) updates on our servers and rebooted the machines. Our development server did not came online anymore due to a problem with the GPU (integrated in CPU). We've replaced (and upgraded) the hardware on that machine and also converted the originally bare-metal machine to a VM (KVM) so we can upgrade it from CentOS5 -> CentOS6 later.

However the machine itself was NOT reinstalled, all data was secured and copied 1:1 as a new image the (new) VM could used to boot.

The problem we have now is MySQL performance. It seems to be mostly related to really simple CREATE TABLE statements. We cannot find if this issue is related to the MySQL upgrade to 5.5.50 or the move to a VM.

The problem:

mysql-slow-querylog

```
# Time: 160610 13:55:50
# User@Host: unittest[unittest] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 7.954247  Lock_time: 0.000049 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use unittest_api_575aaabd9e502;
SET timestamp=1465559750;
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `customer`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `crm_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;
```

(our unittest suite creates a DB structure and this is a table that is created)

You'll notice it took almost 8 seconds to create this table! (Our test-suite now takes 2 minutes instead of 30 seconds)

I also ran this query with profiling:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;

set profiling =1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
    `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `crm_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=25;

set profiling =0;

show profile all for query 1;
```

And this is the output:
[image: slow_query]
The results vary but I do see a lot of high (>1 sec) values), to my opinion this should never take more than one second on a server with little load.

I've tried to make some changes to the my.conf however I did not yet managed to increase performance. I've uploaded our [my.cnf](http://pastebin.com/aWzfmzk8) for reference.

Some details on the server:

- MySQL 5.5.50
- CentOS 5.11

Host:

- i7 6300
- 32GB RAM
- 2x 1TB harddisk

VM:

- 4 cores
- 16GB RAM

I cannot believe this is only from bare-metal => VM. Can anyone point us in the right direction? If more information is needed let me know.

Additional information:

- VM Config:
- CPU Load: low (~5%)
- iostat output during execution: http://pastebin.com/AHkby04X

Comment: Can you show the output of `virsh dumpxml <vmname>`?

Comment: @shodanshok Here you go: http://pastebin.com/0tfYiaE2

Comment: did you checked iowait and cpu load during testing?

Comment: "2 x 1TB harddisk" - slow, terrible IOPS, unfit to run database virtualization (or any database) with any performance requirements.

Comment: @TomTom Yes harddisks are slow compare to SSD's, however this is a development server. We've never had any issues (like this) before. The database is really light used. I'm asking here on the difference between pre HW failure and after HW replacement and VM conversion. Yes the performance won't be as 'good' as when it was bare-metal but it should not be so bad that a simple CREATE TABLE statements takes 8 seconds!

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I'm sorry didn't noticed your reply before. CPU load is low, as it is a fast CPU with 4 cores assigned to the VM it sits around ~5% each core. I notice no real difference in load during the "CREATE TABLE"s part of the test. The IOwait ("xx% wa in top right?) is at ~30% Not sure if that is bad.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I've updated the question with iostat output

Answer (score 2):

You did not specified the vdisk cache type, so libvirt is assuming the most safest cache scheme: `directsync`, which imply that all writes are immediately synched to the physical disk.

Such restrictive cache type is generally overkill for modern, cache-aware application, which uses write barriers by themselves to ensure important writes are synched to disk.

Do the following:

- shutdown your machine
- open its configuration via `virt-manager`
- select `virtio disk 1` and, in the right pane, click `advanced`, then `performance options`
- set cache type to `writeback`
- finally, restart your virtual machine.

The VM should be much faster now. However, as you are using a quite old OS (CentOS 5.x), please be sure to enable write barriers inside the guest OS. To do that, you should mount your guest's filesystem with the `barrier=1` mount option (eg: passing it via `/etc/fstab`).

For some other information about caching and barriers, [give a look here](http://www.ilsistemista.net/index.php/virtualization/23-kvm-storage-performance-and-cache-settings-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-62.html?limitstart=0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot do this right now as there are people using the server but I will let you know if it worked!

Comment: Don't forget about enabling barriers inside the guest OS via the `barrier=1` mount option - it is very important to prevent data loss in case of system crash.

Comment: enabling barriers does not prevent against data loss, it ensures that filesystem maintains integrity in a crash - not the same thing at all. And trying to ensure that a single node is as reliable as possible is rarely a good solution to HA.

Comment: Journaled applications (as MySQL) use barriers to prevent partial writes and unexpected data loss: they guarantee that if a write is acknowledged to the user, data really are on stable storage (directly in the main filesystem or in the journal log). Fully journaled filesystem (eg: ext4 with data=journaled mount option) are even safer, but they pay a significant price in performance.

Comment: I've make the change and indeed it is a (huge) improvement. For example our unittest suite that took 2+ minutes will now run in ~50 seconds. However I'm not there yet. In my local vagrant box it runs in 30 seconds (also from HDD). When I look at the mysql processlist it seems (again) that  CREATE TABLE statements are slow. If you want I can create some code that does xx CREATE TABLES on our test server, a (busy) production server (also VM & HDD) and my local vagrant box? Would that be useful?

Comment: Whoops, you can clearly see it if I execute a single test (that will still create the entire database structure) that will take 30 seconds while that would normally take only a few seconds.

Comment: Can you report the exact model number of your disks, both on the old (bare-metal) server and the new one? I suspect the new ones are 4K disks, and the partition/filesystem can be out of alignement.

Comment: @shodanshok The harddisk is the same as before. However the installation on that disk is changed (was: CentOS5, now: CentOS6+kvm). The disks are WDC WD1002FAEX-00Z3A0 (1TB WD Black)

Comment: I am not sure there is anything you can optimize more. After all, your performance are now 2-3X better than what you had before cache optimization.

Comment: Well it seemed that way yes last Friday night, however with some users working on the server nog the performance is back to well... crap. At least it is not even close to what it was.

Comment: disk scheduler might also matter (noop or deadline), sync-method used (O_DSYNC, vs O_DIRECT), additional mount options (noatime and nodiratime). what RAID option was used?

Comment: The root filesystem is mounted with "defaults,barrier=1". The RAID is Linux Software Raid (again: as it was before).